# OpenLink Virtuoso Facets Webservice: post JSON-formatted query, request output in JSON

Tags: faceted-search, virtuoso

[OpenLink Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) Faceted Browser package provides both a user interface, and a web service (Faceted Browsing Service) for faceted search against a Virtuoso triple store. The [service is described on their website](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtuosoFacetsWebService).

According to the documentation, the service "takes an XML or JSON description of the desired view (via HTTP POST), and generates the reply in the form of XML or JSON documents comprised of the requested data".

The documentation has plenty of examples of sending requests and receiving responses in the XML format, which I was able to reproduce successfully and run against my local installation of Virtuoso. However, there are no examples with queries and responses encoded in JSON.

I can probably dissect the Faceted Browser source code (can be found in github) and figure out how to format the queries as JSON and force the service to return JSON output instead of XML, but perhaps someone has already done that and can post a couple of working examples with JSON input/output here.

Also, for the XML-formatted queries and responses, are there links to corresponding XML Schema Definition files somewhere in the documentation? I could not find them.